# Minkowski Addition of Sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I understand that the Minkowski Addition of $A + B = \{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$. I have two questions.

1. Is $4\mathbb Z + \mathbb N$ equivalent to $\mathbb Z$?
2. How would I go about proving #1? Can I use the double-containment method by proving that $4\mathbb Z + \mathbb N \subseteq \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z \subseteq 4\mathbb Z + \mathbb N$?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I believe that $4\mathbb{Z} + \{0,1,2,3\} = \mathbb{Z}$.  It may be easier to prove this, as you can argue any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ can uniquely be written as $x = 4y+r$ for $r\in\{0,1,2, 3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **equal** instead of *equivalent*, as this is the correct terminology for sets. And before talking about the answer
2. Yes. This is a good approach. One direction/inclusion is immediate, namely $4\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{Z}$. For the other, just argue why the following holds:

> Any integer number can be written as 
>   $$z=4k+l, \quad k\in\mathbb{Z}, l=\{0,1,2,3\}$$
>   from which you can conclude. The keyword here is *euclidean division*

Answer (score 0):

For $z\in \mathbb Z$ let $f(z)$ be the largest integer-multiple of $4$ that's less than $z.$ Then $f(z)\in 4\mathbb Z.$ And $z-f(z)\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ because $f(z)+4\geq z>f(z).$

So $z=f(z)+(z-f(z))\in 4\mathbb Z+\{1,2,3,4\}.$

As this holds for each $z\in \mathbb Z$ we have therefore $\mathbb Z\subset 4\mathbb Z+\{1,2,3,4\}\subset 4\mathbb Z+\mathbb N\subset \mathbb Z.$